# Python regex £ sign

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8

I'm reading from a text file which contains pound signs (£):

```
f = open(file, 'r')
string = f.read()
f.close()
```

Along with some other regex operations, I want to remove these pound signs, and write the string to a new file. The closest I've got to making this work is the following code:

```
n = re.compile(unichr(163))
string = n.sub('', string)
```

This seems to find the pound signs correctly, but instead of replacing them with nothing, the `£` are converted this symbol: `Â`

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: You should be very particular with encoding when dealing with special characters. Make sure you know the encoding of the file you open, the one you write and the one of your own code. If you use Python 2.x, please tag your question accordingly, as encoding handling is different in the two versions.

Comment: use `codecs.open` instead of open, and then just do `string.replace(u'£', '')` , there is no need for regex here.

Comment: @alessadro: the Python source code encoding has *nothing* to do with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

## Summary:

> In utf8, `£` maps to raw bytes `\xc2\xa3`. The `re` module allows for string substitution to occur between unicode and byte encoded strings, which is an error.

It's my opinion that J.F. Sebastian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317102/1213041) is more succint, but here is a walkthrough.

## Details:

Calls to `read()` return a bytestring.

To illustrate, lets create the following file `durp`:

```
echo -n "£" > durp
```

The next command gets the contents of the file in hex:

```
$ cat durp | xxd  | cut -d " " -f 2
c2a3
```

**Note:** Visiting this [url](http://cdosborn.github.io/unicode?cp=163/) will display `£` in multiple encodings.

These are the raw bytes which constitute `£`. What does python do with the file when its read?

```
$ python
> f = open("durp")
> f.read()
'\xc2\xa3'
```

It doesn't know what the encoding is so it represents the bytes in their escaped hex form.

Let's import your code:

```
> import re
> r = re.compile(u'£')
> u'£'
u'\xa3'
```

That last line is just to see what we're making a pattern on. This is the source of the error.

Now we perform the substitution on the contents of the file:

```
> r.sub('', '\xc2\xa3')
'\xc2'
```

Which is conceivable but wrong. We substituted `'\xa3'` for `''` in `'\xc2\xa3'` and got `'\xc2'`. This is an error in `re`, because unicode strings are being mixed with bytestrings. It doesn't not make sense to perform substitions of characters that have different encodings. This is essentially substituting bytes rather than characters.

J.F. Sebastian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317102/1213041) explains how your terminal would interpret `'\xc2'` as `Â`.

Comment: it is wrong or at best misleading. The presence of `unichr` indicates that OP uses Python 2. `read()` returns a bytestring (a sequence of bytes) in this case -- no unicode type in the picture anywhere (you can write *anything* in to the file and `read()` will work anyway). If you see `Â£` when you print two *bytes* `print b'\xc2\xa3'` means that your terminal/console uses `cp1252` or similar character encoding (I would see `£` because my terminal uses utf-8 character encoding). [The real issue is that OP mixes unicode and bytes that exposes the bug in `re` module](http://goo.gl/kczhRe).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think my answer has utility in walking through the OP's code and error. It did have several errors which I believe I've corrected. Your post is succinct and demonstrates better understanding of unicode in Python. Props.

Comment: It is better but it is still misleading. All bytes in a bytestring are just bytes. It is irrelevant for the issue whether some of them in the ascii range -- your confusion comes from the fact that Python's `repr(bytestring)` shows some bytes (from `graph` class) as characters e.g., `b'\x22\x20\x22'` is usually shown as `b'" "'` -- note: the literals (constants in the Python source code) are different but the bytestrings are the same -- they consist of the same sequence of bytes: 34, 32, 34 (it is more prominent in Python 3 where indexing a `bytes` object returns a Python `int`: `b'a'[0] == 97`

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in `re` module in Python 2 that allows to mix unicode pattern and an input bytestring: it silently encodes the pattern using `latin-1` encoding that leads to the incorrect result. Python 3 correctly raises `TypeError` here.

```
>>> u'\N{POUND SIGN}'.encode('latin-1')
'\xa3'
>>> u'\N{POUND SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')                                                                     
'\xc2\xa3'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(u'\N{POUND SIGN}', '', u'\N{POUND SIGN}'.encode('utf-8'))                                      
'\xc2'
>>> print(re.sub(u'\N{POUND SIGN}', '', u'\N{POUND SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')).decode('cp1252'))              
Â
>>> print(re.sub(u'\N{POUND SIGN}', '', u'x\N{POUND SIGN}y'))
xy
```

The solution is to use Unicode for both the pattern and the input string:

```
import io

with io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
     result = file.read().replace(u'\N{POUND SIGN}', '')
```

`codecs` modules does not handle universal newlines correctly, use `io` module instead. The builtin `open()` function in Python 3 is `io.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing 8bit strings and full Unicode strings. @cdosborn has given a great description how this had led to partially replacing chars.

In Python > 2.x, there's two ways to hold text: Strings and Unicode strings. Strings can contain text **encoded** in plain ASCII, ANSI, Windows-1252, UTF-8, UTF-16. The problem is that *you* have to know what encoding the text is in if you need to convert it. Unicode strings on the hand are totally unambiguous as they're the result of an explicit conversion from a string using a known encoding, by using Unicode escape codes (u"\u00A3"), or functions like unichr().

Best practice is to always decode Strings to Unicode on input to your code. Then encode on the way out. This is the default behaviour for Python 3.x and other languages like Java.

If you're working with files, the `codecs` module provide a good way to convert text to Unicode strings on the way in:

```
my_file = codecs.open("filename.txt", "r", "utf-8")
my_unicode_string = my_file.read()
```

*Obviously, if your file is in another encoding, change `utf-8` for the encoding name - See codec names: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings*

If you're dealing with strings from elsewhere (stdin, webforms), convert using:

```
my_unicode_string = "my €uro sign in utf-8".decode("utf-8")
```

*Again, change the `utf-8` argument accordingly*

Once you have a Unicode string, you're free to use it how you wish. To do a simple search and replace for the pound sign do:

```
my_unicode_string.replace(unichr(163), "")
```

To make your code easier to read, you can encode your source code in UTF-8 and declare the encoding. This will mean you don't have to hide Unicode chars in escape sequences or ordinals.

**Putting this altogether:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
my_file = codecs.open("filename.txt", "r", "utf-8")
my_unicode_string = my_file.read()
replaced_unicode_string = my_unicode_string.replace("£", "")
```

Now, if you want to write your `replaced_unicode_string` to another file:

```
my_output_file = codecs.open("another_filename.txt", "w", "utf-8")
my_output_file.write(replaced_unicode_string)
```

Comment: it is `codecs`, not `codec` and you should [use `io` module anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29317102/4279).